# Cargar datos en form wizzard - ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando una aplicación web en **asp.net core**, en la cual estoy cargando un formulario con identificación y nombre para dirigirlo a otro formulario que tiene un formulario WIZARD la cual trae los datos personales del cliente en una ficha, en otra ficha trae el crédito del cliente y por ultimo la tarjeta de crédito para el pago, este pago lo realizo para *payu*.

El problema es que estoy realizando una petición **ajax** para realizar la consulta y siempre me devuelve un dato nulo.

Anexo código:

```
function ValidarExisteContactoPago() {

    var Nombre;
    var IdUsuario;
    if ($("#Nombre").val() !== null || $("#IdUsuario").val() !== null) {
        IdUsuario = $("#IdUsuario").val();
        Nombre = $("#Nombre").val();
        var existeUsuario;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Pago/IndexTC",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                Nombre: Nombre,
                IdUsuario: IdUsuario
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                existeUsuario = true;
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);

                if (data.success) {

                    existeUsuario = true;
                    console.log('Data received: ');
                    console.log(result);
                }
                else {
                    existeUsuario = false;
                    console.log('Data received: ');
                    console.log(result);
                }

            },
                error: function (data) {
                existeUsuario = false;
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        });

    } else {
        existeUsuario = false;
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(data);
    }


    return existeUsuario;
}
```

Codigo C#:

```
        public IActionResult IndexTC(string id)
        {
            Credito Items = new Credito();
            decimal saldo = (from x in demoDrHelpContext.Credito where x.IdUsuario == id select x.Saldo).Sum();   // lengthSum: 19
            Items.Saldo = saldo;
            return Ok(Items);
        }
```

Comment: Hola, indica por favor el código de la Acción `IndexTC`, ya que es la que estás llamando desde la función Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en que la Acción `IndexTC()`, no está recibiendo correctamente los parámetros de entrada desde la llamada AJAX.

Debes definir el `IdUsuario` y el `Nombre` como parámetros. El código quedaría así:

```
    public IActionResult IndexTC(string IdUsuario, string Nombre)
    {
        Credito Items = new Credito();
        decimal saldo = (from x in demoDrHelpContext.Credito 
        where x.IdUsuario == IdUsuario select x.Saldo).Sum();   // lengthSum: 19
        Items.Saldo = saldo;
        return Ok(Items);
    }
```

También modifica la llamada AJAX en la sección `data:`, de la siguiente manera:

```
  data: {
            IdUsuario: $("#IdUsuario").val(),
            Nombre: $("#Nombre").val()                
        },
```